# php - how to echo a value if the variable is empty

Tags: php, string

I know how to do something like this in Perl, but not sure how to do it the correct way in Php...

Say I have a string called: $string

What is the proper way to do this:

```
echo "Code is " . ($string || "Great");
```

So it would print $string to the browser, IF it had value, otherwise it would print "Great" to the browser.

do I have to use a if statement or is there a way to do it like this:

($string == "s1") ? 's2':'s1'

Sorry for my Php Ignorance :)

-Richard

Comment: The PHP way to do it is `echo "Code is " . ($string ?: "Great");` Read about the [conditional ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "Code is " . (empty($string) ? "Great" : $string);
```

Comment: that is what I was looking for. It worked. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this to check if the string is set:

```
echo (isset($string) && $string !== '')? $string : "Great";
```

When only use [empty](http://php.net/manual/de/function.empty.php) a string which contains only '0' will be empty.

Comment: Overcomplicated. `echo $string ?: "Great"` does the job more straightforwardly.